# Circle is not perfect PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm kinda new with the PIL was wondering why my circle is not perfect. Is there a fix for this? Thanks.

here's my code:

```py
avatar_image = avatar_image.resize((128, 128))
avatar_size = (avatar_image.size[0] * 3, avatar_image.size[1] * 3)

circle_image = Image.new('L', avatar_size, 0)
circle_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(circle_image)
circle_draw.ellipse((0, 0) + avatar_size, fill=255)
mask = circle_image.resize(avatar_image.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
avatar_image.putalpha(mask)

final = ImageOps.fit(avatar_image, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
final.putalpha(mask)

final.show()
```

Draw Circle: right side of the circle looks off

[image]

Circle with Picture:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error, commonly caused by a confusion between size and position which is the case here too.

`image.new` takes a width and height in number of pixels.

`circle_draw.ellipse` takes a start and end position, which is based on a 0-indexed grid.

To get a full circle you need to make the circle one pixel smaller than it is now to fit inside `circle_image`

Comment: Thank you so much!!